# Owner change only for system admin except for one user

Tags: validation-rule, owner

I have set up a validation rule so that certain profiles are the only ones allowed to change owner.

```
ISCHANGED(OwnerId) &&
$User.ProfileId <> "00e1I000001WfzK" &&
$User.ProfileId <> "00e1I000000dqsR" &&
$User.ProfileId <> "00e1I000000S8BL" &&
$User.ProfileId <> "00e1I000000aAM2"
```

However, I want anyone outside of that profile to be able to send to 1 user (we have a graveyard user). How do I manipulate this validation rule in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What does "be able to send to 1 user" have to do with changing ownership?  Also you have multiple profiles listed, so which specific profiles does "outside of that profile" refer to?  Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules are best thought of as ***in***validation rules.

That is, instead of your rule telling you when a record is valid, it tells you when it is invalid.

You have the first part worked out.

> If the ownerId is changing, and the person changing it is not any of your 4 profiles, the change is invalid.

The second part is simple

> If the ownerId is changing, and it's not changing to [graveyard user], the change is invalid.

Now, how to put them together? Building a truth table can help. Let's use `A` to represent the first condition, and `B` to represent the second.

| A | B | Disallow Change? | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | false | OwnerId is not changing, it's being changed by an allowed profile, or it's changing to the graveyard user |
| false | true | false | For the first condition to be false, the OwnerId must be changing and it must be from one of the allowed profiles. For the second condition to be true, ownerId must be changing to a non-graveyard user. Given that those 4 profiles are allowed to make any change, we don't care that the second condition fails |
| true | false | false | OwnerId is changing to the graveyard user |
| true | true | true | OwnerId is changing to a non-graveyard user, and it's not being done by an allowed profile |

Fortunately for us, the truth table with 2 inputs that must both be true is the `AND` operator.

So you should simply be able to `AND` the conditions together.

In pseudo-code format, breaking `A` and `B` into their constituents...
`(a && !b && !c && !d && !e) && (a && !f)`

factoring out the common bits from both sub-expressions
`a && ((!b && !c && !d && !e) && (!f))`

and simplifying, we arrive at the expected "you can just `AND` your new condition with the existing validation rule", with `f` being "Owner is the graveyard user" (so `!f` == owner is *not* the graveyard user)
`a && !b && !c && !d && !e && !f`

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out use of Custom Permissions is a better approach than assigned profile names/IDs.